# Can a with return cursor in DB2 be parameterized?

Tags: plsql, db2

Below is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ds_grp_heatmap_product_test ()
SPECIFIC ds_grp_heatmap_product_test  
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
        DECLARE c_hm_report(v_sal INTEGER)                    
        CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR 
        select *
        from emp where salary<v_sal;
    open c_hm_report(2000);
END;
```

This code is giving compilation error any idea what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Its `DB2` or `PLSQL` both are different

Comment: Its plsql in DB2.

Comment: `PLSQL` is proprietary to `Oracle`. You must rename your question somthing as `Procedure in DB2` and remove `PLSQL`  tag

Answer (score 1):

Your code is SQLPL (as distinct from PLSQL).    Depending on your Db2 server version and configuration you can also write PLSQL (Oracle compatibility mode of Db2).   You are getting compilation errors because the above syntax is not valid for SQLPL.

The code below might be what you seek: the parameter in this case is supplied as an input to the stored procedure, adjust the type as necessary, or you can set the variable v_sal  via other means:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ds_grp_heatmap_product_test (in v_sal integer)
SPECIFIC ds_grp_heatmap_product_test  
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
        DECLARE c1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR 
        select *
        from emp where salary < v_sal;
    open c1;
END
@
```